# Writing dataframe to parquet files vs Azure Storage - poor performance

Tags: python, azure, performance, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing a dataframe to parquet files like this:

```
items = []
for i in range(5 * 1000 * 1000):
  time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.ffffff")
  items.append((random.random(), i % 16, time))
columns = StructType([StructField('Id', DoubleType(), True), StructField('Num', IntegerType(), True), StructField('Message', StringType(), True)])
test_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(items, columns)

test_dataframe.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(test_parquet_path + '/' + suffix + '.parquet') # measuring only this
```

The code is running in the Azure cloud. The target is a standard storage account, hot tier, in LRS mode.
The data frame has 5 million rows and the resulting files are ~60 MB and take ~3 seconds to write, so the writing speed is only ~20 MB/sec.
Any ideas why it's so slow and is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Where is that code running?

Comment: @luk2302 Spark pool in Azure Synapse.

Comment: Is time of execution linearly proportional to dataframe size? 2.5million take ~1.5 seconds?  Side note: isn't it better to store integer timestamp instead of much larger datetime string? It will be faster to write and read later (probably including converting to string when needed)

Comment: @dankal444 data is purely arbitrary, just to fill the dataframe. Yes it's quite linear, so writing 10x data takes ~30 seconds.

Comment: Did you check if the hardware is saturated? For example the storage device or the network. Without this information you cannot know are good your code is and if it is even possible to build a faster code.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's quite linear. It seems there is a limitation somewhere. I think that azure has defined the maximum speed and there is no way to make it faster.